# move.js synchronisation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to make an animated leaderboard using move.js (). There are four sections, and when loaded it should hide the people who are not in first place, do a bit of an animation of the first place people and then fade in the other users.

I have fiddled it up: https://jsfiddle.net/muwc4enz/

and the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // on load, animate it...               
    // set opacity to 0
    $('[data-position!="0"]').css({'opacity':'0'}); 
    $('[data-position!="0"]').addClass("fadein");

    // now display the first place people.. 
    $('.leader_section_1st').each(function(i, obj) {
        // now animate...
        move(obj).scale(3.0).duration(500).end(function() {
            move(obj).scale(1.0).duration(500).end(function() { 
                // and load the rest of the section...
                $('[data-sectionid="'+i+'"]').css({'opacity':'100'});
            });
        });
    });         
});
```

As you can see, I dont get the animations at all, but I do get the fade. After the fade IN, it goes back to 0 opacity again. I am unsure of why this might be the case and have checked it isnt rerunning the document load function, it isnt.

Without the funky opacity stuff the animation does at least work on THREE of the people at the top of the leader boards, but here is the other problem: The user at the very top, named FAILURE in the fiddle, only animates half correctly... as if it got halfway through the animation and got stuck.

As an extra piece of info, the content is loaded dynamically via a php script.

I suspect its an issue with the timing of when things run, as everything seems to run and I don't get errors (I was worried about the syntax relating to the data variables). I was wondering if anybody could see any reason from the code why it would not do what I expect... which was to reiterate:

1. Make everything except the top people in each category invisible.
2. Make those top students really big (scale 3) and then quickly small again ( to scale 1)
3. When the top students become small again the rest of the students should fade in, and stay faded in.

Thanks.
Alex

Comment: Not sure what you want !

Comment: Sure, i have appended my question at the bottom to be more specific of what I expect it to look like. I am requesting advise on why it might not be working as I had intended.